# Error when taking some variables from multiple lines with same pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am really new to perl. I need to grab some variables from multiple lines with same pattern using perl script.

These are the example of multiple lines with same pattern and are stored in input.txt:

```
input -input_port -port top_port 21.303 [open_port -op {input_port[0]} -file "file_name == top_input_port[0]"]
input -input_port -port bot_port 98.324 [open_port -op {input_port[10]} -file "file_name == bot_input_port[10]"]
```

The format of the line is :

```
input -input_port -port portname value [open_port -op {input_port[10]} -file "file_name == filename"]
```

So, i tried to create this script using examples in Google:

```
#! /tools/perl/5.8.8/linux/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    if ($_ =~ /^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+
              \[(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s
              \{(\S+)\[(\d+)\]\}\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s*==\s(\S+)*"\]$/x ) {
        $io = $1;
        $io_port = $2;
        $port = $3;
        $portname = $4;
        $value = $5;
        $openclose = $6;
        $op = $7;
        $io_num = $8;
        $number = $9;
        $filetype = $10;
        $file = $11;
        $file_name = $12;
        print "$io $portname $value $file_name\n";
    }
}
```

I only want to print $io, $portname, $value and $file_name. However, it displays compilation errors. How do i fix this error?

I am expecting the output to be in new txt file:

input top_port 21.303 top_input_port[0]

input bot_port 98.324 bot_input_port[10]

Comment: Sow the error message please

Comment: show some expected output instead of your expected capture group... that will help

Comment: Just guessing since there is no errors. Did you forget to put 'my' infront of the vars?

Comment: what's with the `if $_` regular expression? if you are reading this from file, does the lines differ? why not just split into array from string?

Comment: I forgot to put use strict; and use warnings; just know. After that, it does not displays error but the output im expecting is not there. I really do not know much on perl.

Comment: The output is not there because the regex fails to match. You're using `\d+` to match numerals like `21.303` whilst the dot is not included in the `\d` class. Use `[\d.]+` or `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead.

Comment: After i changed it, where should i see the output because its like nothing happen?

Comment: Ensure you declare every used variable with `my`. Otherwise, the code should be working fine: https://ideone.com/Q4CbqF

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, that regex is way too complicated. You're doing a load of matching, and it's brittle.

Most likely you're being tripped up on `21.303` isn't matched by `\d+`.

So your regex breaks, and that's... that.

But can I suggest a different approach? Don't regex  the whole thing, that means complicated and hard to read - and brittle - regular expressions.

Why not instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 

   my ( $io ) = m/^(\w+)/; #first word on line
   my ( $portname, $value ) = m/-port (\w+) ([\d\.]+)/;  #look for 'port' keyword. 
   my ( $file_name ) = m/file_name == (\S+)\"/; #look for 'file_name' keyword 

   print "$io $portname $value $file_name\n";
}

__DATA__
input -input_port -port top_port 21.303 [open_port -op {input_port[0]} -file "file_name == top_input_port[0]"]
input -input_port -port bot_port 98.324 [open_port -op {input_port[10]} -file "file_name == bot_input_port[10]"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but my data is in input.txt, how do i run the perl script for input.txt that is in the same folder as my perl script? and is it possible for the output to be in new .txt file?

Comment: Use `while ( <> ) { ` like you do in your original script. And open a file for output and print to that .

Comment: Hi @Sobrique, i've tried using the code that you suggest but it appears error: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string for grabbing $file_name. The $io, $portname and $value works fine.

Comment: That means the regex isn't matching for some reason. It did for your sample data. So see how that differs.

Comment: Hi @Sobrique, your answer works just fine, however, in the input.txt, there are not only input lines, there are also output line, that is why i think i need to use the if condition eventhough its complicated right? because as i only wants input, not output, im afraid it will take everything.

Comment: Well, if your sample data doesn't reflect your question, it won't work the same. 

So - how about `next unless m/^input/;`